# OneDrive - Android sign-in error

Tags: onedrive

Same error for 2 weeks now: get notification saying sign-in error for one-drive, I try and enter password, says email address or password is wrong, so I reset password, then it goes away for an hour or two, then same error, repeat. Have googled but doesn't seem to be a solution out there - any help here? I would delete it but I like the back up service.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data/cache for the app? Also could try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I cleared the app cache and force stopped the app and it all worked again.